# How can i make vertices that are along an edge but not part of it cut into the edge and do it for many vertices?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

https://webm.red/L9JA.webm

you can see the problem here through the webm and i want to fix it for the entire mesh and not just a few vertices.

Comment: I'm not sure there's any simple solution, I guess you have to create a new vertice on the edge and merge it with the other vertice

Comment: Well you could write a python script that checks for every edge whether there is a vertice in it and if that is the case you could delete that edge, connect the original vertices of the edge with the new vertice and fill the faces

Comment: You can try to select them via Select Similar menu; select one mentioned vertex and press Shift+G > Amount of Connected Edges or Amount of Adjacent Faces. Note to keep track of other areas of the mesh if the selection doesn't interfere with something important (and selects more than required). Once selected use X > Dissolve Vertices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Degenerate Disolve function with all selected(<kbd>a</kbd>) in edit mode(<kbd>Tab</kbd>) for that. You can access it from the <kbd>space</kbd> search menu or from Mesh -> Clean Up -> Degenerate Disolve :

[image]

It dissolves zero area faces and zero length edges.